# CSS for Projector view

Tags: html, css, project

Currently for my project I am using the following CSS for the body according to my laptop resolution

```
body {
    font: 11px 'Lucida Grande',Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans serif;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1260px;
}
```

So It's work fine when the browser resized, with the scroll bar.

My question is when I try this layout in the projector It comes first time with the scroll. Is it possible to write CSS for the projector as the resolution of the projector is different say 1024px.

- How can I write the css to project in projector ?
- Is there any other fix apart from following ?

  1. Specify the `width:100%`
  2. Specify the width such that the space will be there which auto adjust at the time of projection mean to say that the `width:680px` kind of.
  3. `media="projection"` which works for opera browser only, in case what about other browser ?

Thank you.

Comment: you can use `media="projection"`

Comment: @KheemaPandey: I am using webobject framework. CSS media queries are compatible with that or not ? Can you please provide me the syntax for the media="projection".

Comment: As far I knows only opera browser support it.

Comment: @KheemaPandey: So what is the solution in case of other browsers. Only width:100%. OR is there any ?

Comment: see this link.. might be helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378206/projection-media-query-browser-support-and-workarounds

Comment: You shouldn't use absolute width for the body. Prefer to use relative values (percentages or vw). It will be responsive this way.

Comment: you should avoid using width:1260px as what works for you will seldom work for other people / devices. Try using relative value of width:100% if you want the contents to span the whole of the browser space.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How reliable is the "projection" media type in css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505398/how-reliable-is-the-projection-media-type-in-css)